# Sharing code between 2 TFSVC repositories with git-tfs

Tags: tfs, git-tfs

I have 2 different TFS repositories (one using Visual Studio Online and another using my own local on premise TFS instance) which I want to keep in sync using git-tfs. How do I need to set things up so that I can work locally in git and push changes up to both repositories? Please note both TFS repositories are using TFSVC.

Comment: It is hard to understand the scenario and why using git-tfs. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the main developer of git-tfs, believe me, that's not possible...

Git-tfs can only manage one TFVC repository.

Comment: I decided to go with other sync methods since this is not supported. For now I'm using a manual ROBOCOPY command, will try and hey something better going later

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not support.

If you want to sync Visual Studio Online and local TFS. You can use the **TFS Integration Tools** to setup a unidirectional sync, that should allow you to ensure that a TeamProject on your local TFS system remains in sync. However, they are complicated to setup and will be painfull to run. And There are commercial options that are ridiculously expensive, like OpsHub.